# CSRF token error for django app when deploying to AWS server

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, csrf

I have a django site that runs fine locally but when trying to deploy with AWS elastic beanstalk I get  the following error when I try to login (using django allauth)

*Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.*

The logs state:

*Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /accounts/login/*

My settings.py middleware has:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]
```

If I comment out "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware" then it works fine

The form has a csrf_token:

```
<form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <a class="button secondaryAction" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">{% trans "Forgot Password?" %}</a>
  <button class="primaryAction btn btn-primary" type="submit">{% trans "Sign In" %}</button>
</form>
```

Any advice as to how to fix and why it runs ok locally but not when deployed appreciated

Comment: [django-cors-headers](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)

Comment: You found any solution for this? I'm kinda having the same problem

Comment: @Yorbjörn I got it fixed but I dont think I figured precisely what I was doing wrong. I think onnne of the things I did was went through every one of the django settings in my settings file, read the docs about what it did, and set it appropriately. I think the other thing that was key was getting my https working correctly ( it thnnk that perhaps that was why it wasnt working when deployed as had not correctly set up https)

Answer (score 1):

If you've recently upgraded to Django 4.0, you now need to set CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS - that fixed the error in my case. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins

Answer (score 1):

Try the following order in your middleware as fix:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

> The order in MIDDLEWARE matters because a middleware can depend on other middleware. For instance, AuthenticationMiddleware stores the authenticated user in the session; therefore, it must run after SessionMiddleware. See Middleware ordering for some common hints about ordering of Django middleware classes.

Also remember to include these in `settings.py`:

```
# Security & HTTPS settings

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://<your-domain-or-ip>']
```

You can learn more about `Django Middleware` here: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/middleware/#:~:text=The%20order%20in%20MIDDLEWARE%20matters,ordering%20of%20Django%20middleware%20classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/middleware/#:%7E:text=The%20order%20in%20MIDDLEWARE%20matters,ordering%20of%20Django%20middleware%20classes).

Answer (score 0):

Try to reorder the middlewares. They are exequted sequentially. So any middleware passes the request to the next and if something has been blocked it will not be available for the next middleware and so on

Comment: thanks, I have put     "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware" at the top but have the same issue

Answer (score -2):

The way you describe it working when you comment out the csrfmiddleware sounds identical to the problem I was facing. The way I solved it was by adding a csrf_exempt tag to the ACS endpoint. Credit goes to this short conversation from Github where a user had the same problem.

https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml/issues/146

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: adding `csrf_exempt` will just make your post requests unsecure, because the backend would not need to check the origin of the request.