# Django Kubernetes Ingress CSRF Cookie not sent

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, django-rest-framework, amazon-eks

Asking this question here because It's been a couple of days and I can't find anything useful.

Problem: I have an app deployed to a Kubernetes cluster running on AWS EKS with a custom docker image on AWS ECR. The app works fine with GET requests but not with POST ones. The error given is `Errore 403 forbidden CSRF Token not sent`. Django version is 2.2.24 on DRF 3.11.2. I already added CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS in settings.py, nothing changed.

The ingress I'm using is AWS's Application Load Balancer set like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: django
  labels:
    name: django
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":80}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: "alta"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.order: "2"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: traffic-port
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /v1/app
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: "15"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-timeout-seconds: "5"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: "200"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthy-threshold-count: "2"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/unhealthy-threshold-count: "2"
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: djangoapp-cluster-ip
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions, the CSRF cookie value was masked.

try this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#how-it-works)

also think decorator can help you

**views.py**

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name="post")
```

Comment: Ok, but what if it does not work with django admin page? Plus this app has already been deployed (and it currently is) on another platform and there it works fine. Only now that we're migrating to aws i get this error

Comment: @AbelHristodor see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69849775/csrf-token-error-for-django-app-when-deploying-to-aws-server